# windows store app with photos as static content

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am making an windows store application and one of the requirements is that it must not use data connection. The application includes a lot of photos (around 400, all compressed as much as possible, around 8 kb each).

What would be the best practice handling this situation? How should I "preload" them in to the application?

Comment: What do you mean "preload"? Like, put them in memory? The app should automatically cache commonly used images, and all image loading should be async, so your ui shouldn't take a large hit from loading images in. You *could* load them into memory at startup, but that could take a *lot* of memory.

Comment: It should also be noted that 8kb on disk does not equate to that size in memory. While in memory, each is inflated to that of a full BMP, so you largely lose the benefits of compression.

Comment: @NateDiamond : wrong use of the word "preload" i guess. i am talking about storing them in local storage / database so that they come bundled with the application and does not need to be downloaded. usual scenario would be to keep them in the filesystem, but in winrt case I could not find a way to store them to local storage via some kind of localstorage explorer and don't think that keeping them in assets folder would be a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement for zero net connectivity is real, then you have two options.

ONE. You can ship your app, and request that the user get the images from some other location and then give them to your app, loading the image in a somewhat manual way.

I know this does not sound ideal, but I wanted to acknowledge it was an option.

TWO. You can ship your app with the images embedded inside the installation package. This means as soon as your app installs, the user has all the images, no net necessary.

Here's how:

1. Create a new folder in your project, call it "Images" or something.
2. Drag your images into that folder (using Visual Studio).
3. Refer to your images like this "ms-appx:///Images/MyImage.jpg"

Note: it's up to you how you keep track of all your images, you **could** iterate through the folder over and over again, but it's probably best you just hard code the list in some class.

It's really that easy.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just store them in your project solution and refer to them in your code using the ms-appx:/// format?

Also if you are using so many images, prefer jpg images or compress your images using

https://tinypng.com/

Hope that helps.